# Locking GIT Files So that They Donot Merge

Tags: git, bitbucket

We are using BitBucket Cloud for one of our private repositories, and we need to basically lock few of our very old files (.java) which are very sensitive, and nobody changes in those files.

I just wanted to know some kind of a locking mechanism to those files so that if they come in the pull request, either the pull request denies it, or they kinda don't get merged.

Hope I am clear in my question and the thing which I am trying to achieve.

Please note: We don't use Bitbucket on our Server, we use it on Bitbucket cloud, hence I guess it does some File Level attribute changes might not help.

Something similar is present in GIT Lab:

1.docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html 
2. gitolite.com/gitolite/locking/index.html

Thanks,
Kushagra

Comment: You can lock branches, but not individual files. This is also not handled by git, but by bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks  @evolutionxbox for the update.I just didn't uderstood the last part of your sentence but by bitbucket, -

==============
Although, I wish we had this kinda feature developed in bitbucket as the something similar is present at 

1.https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/file_lock.html
2. http://gitolite.com/gitolite/locking/index.html

Comment: I'd check their community pages, maybe it's been implemented? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Is-there-any-file-locking-process-in-bitbucket/qaq-p/35776

Comment: Yup, Done.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Is-there-any-file-locking-process-in-bitbucket/qaq-p/35776#U761625